# There is no external DVD Rom in Bios in UEFI mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, uefi, gpt

I need to install Windows 10 on my laptop (ACER Aspire 3). My hard disk scheme is GPT and I need to boot my windows in UEFI mode.

After connecting my external DVD ROM in UEFI mode my laptop can't find the external DVD ROM.  In legacy mode, however, it detects my external DVD ROM easily and I can set priority for DVD ROM but my disk is GPT and I can't install Windows.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: UEFI will only list a device that the firmware detects is bootable in that mode.  If your external device is not being listed it means that media cannot be booted in UEFI mode.

Comment: Assuming there's data on the hard drive: why must you install windows 10? Can you clear the hard drive? Please give more info on why you are installing windows.

Comment: Toggle secure boot to check as well

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, before buying an external device how I can understand it could be detectable or not. Actually the laptop's owner is my friend and he told me to install windows 10 on it without losing other drives information. the secure boot is disabled ( is read-only property)

Comment: so it looks like you must set an admin BIOS password in order to toggle3 secure boot on or off. Secure Boot enabled can/will prevent bootable removable media. https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27072/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have disabled the secure boot but still I can't see my external DVD device. I restarted my system many times to check the detection process.